# How to import source code in Eclipse as Project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've downloaded log4j source code (`apache-log4j-2.11.2-src.zip`) from below location

```
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/download.html
```

But When am trying to import it as a existing project in Eclipse, Its not showing the finish button enabled with error no project found.

Can anyone help me how can I import this source code as a project in Eclipse ?

Thanks

Comment: apache-log4j-2.11.2 is a Maven Project, just import it as a Maven project to Eclipse.

Comment: Why do you want to *import* it instead of using it as a *dependency*?

Comment: Can you be more specific, what source files are you importing from? which application/IDE was it created with? which version of Eclipse was this project created from? clarify this. Otherwise, you might have to create an empty project, then copy & paste each file. You might also need to use Eclipse add on to import existing project.

Comment: @chrylis, I'm trying to drill down the code so that I could see how its working until all  appenders and logger gets initialized...! Am doing this just for my learning purpose..!

Comment: Generally speaking, you'll want to set up a Maven or Gradle project and add it as a project dependency. Eclipse will automatically download the source code and make it available for navigation. (Note also that log4j is obsolete and you should look at slf4j or perhaps log4j2.)